# RestKit object mapping without store in database

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

Actually I've project in which I'm using RestKit 0.22.

In my code I've added object mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *materialMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Material class])
                                                       inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];
...
RKResponseDescriptor *responseMaterialsDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:materialMapping
                                                                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                            pathPattern:urlMaterials
                                                                                                keyPath:kRestApiMAterialsKeyPath
                                                                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseMaterialsDescriptor];
```

Generally this code works OK, and after request proper url I get correct response and have stored objects to local database.

Now I want request the same url but after mapping JSON response to Material objects not store results to database. I want to insert all items after some modifications. Do you have any suggestions how can I avoid to store/save objects to DB by RestKit?

Comment: Why aren't you setting identification attributes and allowing RestKit to update existing items? Or you mean you only want to update existing items and ignore new items (in which case KVC validation is appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to add some attributes or modify the existing attribute after mapping then you should use mappingMetadata and create responseDescriptors from it.

```
[materialMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"@metadata.property1": @"property1", @"@metadata.property2": @"property2"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *materialResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:materialResponseDescriptor pathPattern:@"somPath" keyPath:@"" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Then add the response descriptor to the **RKObjectManager** and create a **RKManagedObjectRequestOperation** for fetching from remote url,

```
  RKRoute *route = [[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] router] routeSet] routeForName:routeName];
  [self cancelAllRequestWithMethod:route.method matchingPath:route.pathPattern];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [_objectManager requestWithPathForRouteNamed:routeName object:nil parameters:nil];
  RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] responseDescriptors]];
  operation.managedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;
  operation.managedObjectCache = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].managedObjectCache;
  operation.savesToPersistentStore = YES;
```

Now, set the mapping metadata ie. this is the value that will be mapped to the original property while the mapping is being done,

```
[operation setMappingMetadata:@{@"property1": value1, @"property2": value2}];
```

Then, enqueue operation and it should map the custom value to the properties. Note, the property1 and property are the attribute in the entity and you do not create responseDescriptor for it.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it's not exactly what should I do. Based on mapped materials collection I want to do some conditional update process in my application and insert only updated items.

Comment: If you wish to change the object just before the save occurs, use - setWillSaveMappingContextBlock: method on RKManagedObjectRequestOperation. Loop through the objects that you are interested in then delete those from the context before the context actually saves.

Comment: By the way RestKit suggests you to use KVC valition on managed object https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation